connect to RoboForex-Demo account with python
The following code is for entering Metatrader and getting account information. The program opens correctly, but through the Python program, it cannot enter the account and print its information. If we can manually enter the account with this information in the MetaTrader program, just note that this RoboForex server is for MetaTrader 4. Please tell me a solution to solve the problem.
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\RoboForex MT4 Terminal\\terminal.exe'
login = 501107640   
password = 'pzhv8qp'
server = 'RoboForex-Demo'
mt5.initialize(path=path)
mt5.login(server=server, login=login, password=password)
account_info = mt5.account_info()
print(account_info)



